# Display two different section in crystal report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I want to display two different section in one crystal report. In my report i have created two section but they both display same data as you can saw in below image.

[image]

What setting is needed for displaying different data? Thanks.

Here image of my crystal report design

[image]

Comment: Can you explain some more? What are the two sections supposed to show? Are you using grouping? Maybe show a screenshot of your report design.

Comment: @campagnolo_1 In crystal report i want to display yearly transaction of different employee..i am trying to display data of two employee in one report but it displays data of one employee two times

Comment: Then most likely you put the fields in the wrong section. Can you post a screenshot of your report design?

Comment: I am uploading but i tell you that i have created two section of details sections

Comment: @campagnolo_1 I have uploaded design of crystal report.

Comment: Now it's much clearer! Give me a few minutes and I will tell you what's going on in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing the report design, here are your issues:
Just because you have two detail sections doesn't mean it will show you two different values.
A report is structured like a book:
The Report Header and Footer are like the cover and back page - you only put information on them that you want to see once.

The Page Header and Footer should contain information that you want to see on every page at the top and bottom.
The Group Header and Footer are used to show information if your data is grouped by certain criteria - like chapters of a book.

The Detail Section shows either all data or the data that pertains to a group - like the text within the chapters.

So, in your case I would create a group that is based on your employee. Put all your header information (the top 3 lines in your report) in the Page Header. In the Group Header you put everything in line 4 and 5. Line 6 through 17 go into the Detail Section. Line 18 with all the totals goes into the Group Footer. Everything from line 19 on goes into the Page Footer.
I hope this makes sense and I'll be more than happy to help out further.